# Enabling Multi User Feature on Realme 3

Tags: rooting, multi-user, oppo-coloros

Can anybody help me with enabling the multiple user feature like stock Android without rooting. I've tried getting the default.prop through adb and changing some properties and then replacing the copy on the phone with that but it wouldn't let me, cause my phone is not rooted and it's telling that I don't have permission. I don't wanna try rooting the phone just yet, cause it's a relatively new unit.So there's probably no stable root guide for it yet and so I don't wanna accidentally hard brick my phone.

Please somebody help me with this.If you have any suggestions and thank you in advance.

Comment: Multi-user feature must be enabled in Android framework while building ROM: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user#applying_the_overlay. If the OEM/ROM developer didn't, you need to modify `framework-res.apk` file at least which is not possible without root.

Answer (score 1):

No, multi user feature is not available in Realme 3 containing Coloros 6.And you cannot enable it without rooting. Realme 3 is based on Mediatek chipset, so you will not get good support for third party ROMs. But in future this phone will get RealmeUI update, which may bring multi user feature.